# Unable to launch application <23 SDK version java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider:

Tags: android, api, classnotfoundexception, runtimeexception, android-fileprovider

I am able to run application on android api 23+ but on device with api 22 its not possible due to this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file,nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4702)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4642)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

I tried some solution with multiDexEnabled, but nothing helped..

Comment: are you using ProGuard?

Comment: proguardFiles 'proguard-trim-logs.txt', getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-android.txt'

Comment: try adding `-keep class android.support.v4.content.FileProvider { *; }` to your `proguard-rules.pro` file.

Comment: didn't helped, still the same error

Comment: I noticed the last line is not copied here, maybe could help

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available